# Run multiple performClick() with UI update

Tags: android

`button.performClick();`

For software demonstration purposes, I want to show the user interface updating after each button `performClick()`. For example, if the Activity was a calculator I can currently simulate the pressing of buttons [1], [2] and [3] using

```
btn1.performClick();
btn2.performClick();
btn3.performClick();
```

However, these updates to the EditText too quickly with no visible pause, i.e. it appears "123" are written to the screen simultaneously. What I want is:-

`btn1.performClick()` updates UI so people can physically see only button press updated to the EditText before the next button does. Similarly with `btn2.performClick()` and then `btn3.performClick()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a library like [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/), and use Solo.waitForText Method to do what you want.

The problem is that we can not determine in advance the time that it will take to display the text, as it depends on the content of your onClick method.

It's why Robotium may be useful for what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, very helpful. Found the Robotium documentation not the easiest and finally used http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_8euppCz3k that was easy to follow

Answer (score 0):

Use handler for `btn2.performClick()` and `btn3.performClick()` like...

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something after 100ms
        btn2.performClick();
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
Thread.sleep(delay);
```

or use

```
handler.postDelayed(Runnable,delay);
```